# Empty String or invalid image AND Filename cannot be empty

Tags: php, file, upload, exif

When no images are selected and form is submitted,
I get these errors:

> Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in /upload.php on line 66
>   Warning: imagecreatefromstring(): Empty string or invalid image in /upload.php on line 66
>   Warning: exif_read_data(): Filename cannot be empty in /upload.php on line 68 
>   Warning: exif_read_data(): Unable to open file in /upload.php on line 68

Here is my code:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
$size = count( $_FILES['file']['name'] );
for( $i = 0; $i < $size; $i++ ) {
    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
    $type = $_FILES['file']['type'][$i];
    $size = $_FILES['file']['size'][$i];
    $temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];

    $rand = rand(1,99999);
    $new_images = "uploads/WinkList_".$rand.$_FILES["file"]["name"][$i];

$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']    [$i]));
$exif = exif_read_data($temp);

//...
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: change :  if (!empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {  ................... to if (isset($_FILES['file']['name'])) {